# Is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n+(-1)^n}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Is the following series convergent?

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n+(-1)^n}$$

I think, the above series is divergent, since

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n+(-1)^n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2+1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3-1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 4+1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt 5-1}+\dots\geq$$
$$\frac{-2}{(\sqrt 3-1)^2}+\frac{-2}{(\sqrt 5-1)^2}+\dots=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{-2}{(\sqrt n-1)^2}$$

And the last series is divergent. IS my argument correct? Thanks.

Comment: You're argument is wrong. It is analogous to showing $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 0$ is divergent since $0+0+0+0+\dots \ge (-1)+(-1)+(-1)+(-1)+\dots$ which is divergent

Comment: Also, the series is convergent by alternating series test.

Comment: Add the even terms to the odd terms.

Comment: Alternating series test requires that the absolute values of the terms *decrease monotonically* to zero, which is not true here.

Comment: This is probably the least contrived example I've seen showing the necessity of the monotonicity requirement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The series diverges since

$$\sum_{n=2}^m \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n} + (-1)^n} = \sum_{n=2}^m \frac{(-1)^n(\sqrt{n} - (-1)^n)}{n - 1}  \\ = \sum_{n=2}^m \frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n - 1}   - \sum_{n=2}^m \frac{1}{n - 1},  $$

with the first series on the RHS convergent by Dirichlet and the second a divergent harmonic series.

Comment: Really nice +1...

Answer (score 7):

No !. when the sign of general term changes, we cannot use comparison test.

Taylor expansion gives,

$$u_n=$$
$$\frac {(-1)^n}{\sqrt {n}}\Bigl(1-\frac {(-1)^n}{\sqrt {n}}+\frac {1}{n}(1+\epsilon (n)\Bigr) $$

$$=\frac {(-1)^n}{\sqrt {n}}-\frac {1}{n}+\frac {(-1)^n}{n\sqrt {n}}(1+\epsilon (n)) $$
$$=v_n+w_n+t_n $$

with

$\sum v_n$ convergent as alernate.

$\sum w_n $ divergent, and
$\sum t_n$ absolutely convergent cause $$|t_n|\sim \frac {1}{n^\frac 32} $$

We conclude that $\sum u_n $ is divergent.