# How to use similar ($\sim)$ functions correctly (if they change their signs)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Are there any restrictions when replacing one function with an equivalent (a similar function)? I've read somewhere that when a function changes its sign in an interval, one cannot freely replace the function with an equivalent. For example, if I have the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin{x}}{x^3+1}$, can I say that $f(x)\sim\frac{\sin{x}}{x^3}$ for $x\in[1, \infty)$? This function is a part of a definite integral, which I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalence is **at one point only**, not an interval like $[1,+\infty)$ as you have written.

Here $x^3\sim x^3+1$ is only true at infinity so to have $f(x)\sim g(x)$ we have to check if their ratio goes to $1$.

$f(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x^3+1}$ and $g(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x^3}$ then the ratio cancels the $\sin$ anyway (so you see we don't care of its sign changes) and we get $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\dfrac{x^3}{x^3+1}\to_\infty 1$

Therefore, the statement below is true

$$\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x^3+1}\sim_\infty\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x^3}$$

Where you have to be careful, is when performing additions. Multiplying equivalents poses no issues, exponentiating you should start to be careful, but adding equivalents is a no-no.

E.g. $f(x)=x^3+x$ and $g(x)=-x^3+7$ then $f(x)\sim x^3$ and $g(x)\sim -x^3$ but we don't have $f(x)+g(x)\sim x^3-x^3=0$ since in fact $f(x)+g(x)=x+7\to\infty$.

This is the reason it does not work inside an integral. An integral is basically a sum of values of $f(x)$ and you cannot rely on an equivalent that changes sign else you would add equivalents which is wrong.

If $f\sim g$ then $\int^{\infty} f$ and $\int^\infty g$ have the same behaviour (convergence, divergence) only when $f,g$ are of constant sign, i.e. we are interested only in absolute convergence, same as required with discrete series.

$a_n\sim b_n$ then $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ have same behaviour only when $a_n,b_n$ have constant sign.

A classical example of constant sign necessity is given by $\sum \dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}$ which is [divergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2423121/399263) while the a priori equivalent $\sum \dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is convergent via the alternated series criteria ($\sqrt{n}\nearrow$).

I have no example in mind for integrals, but the reason is pretty similar.

Comment: I am trying to solve the integral $\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{x^{\alpha}\sin{x}}{x^3+1}}$. I thought that replacing $x^3+1$ with $x^3$ would be wrong because of $\sin{x}$, that changes signs periodically. That's why I posted the question. In this case how should I procede. The logic that  $\int_0^{\infty}{|\frac{x^{\alpha}\sin{x}}{x^3+1}|}< \int_0^{\infty}{\frac{x^{\alpha}}{x^3+1}}$ doesn't really work here.

Comment: Note that for $0\le\alpha<2$ then you can use equivalence since $|f(x)|\le |\frac {x^\alpha}{x^3+1}|\sim_\infty |\frac 1{x^{3-\alpha}}|$ so you have absolute convergence (at infinity). For $\alpha>2$ though you have to proceed otherwise. In zero $\sin(x)\sim x>0$ since your integral is on the right side of zero and you can use equivalence $0\le f(x)\sim_0 x^{\alpha+1}$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. But then I didn't know what to do for $\alpha<2$, so I checked the answers of my book. There I saw an answer, which surprised me: it stated that the integral coverged absolutely for $\alpha<2$ and conditionally for $\alpha\in[2; 3)$. Then I realised that the authors of the book had solved the integral by using the replacement above, and then using the template for $\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\sin{x}}{\x^{\lambda}}}$. I thought that this was wrong so I asked the question. It turns out the authors of the problem can't solve it themselves.